# Flutter - TextField Hides Behind Keyboard

Tags: flutter, dart, keyboard, textfield, bottom-sheet

There is a bottomsheet in flutter code - bottomsheet contains an TextField , While clicking on TextField , Keyboard Covers the TextFeild.

**Below is the code for bottom sheet**

```
showModalBottomSheet(
                          context: context,
                          isScrollControlled: true,
                          builder: (BuildContext buildContext) {
                            return SizedBox(
                              child: Wrap(
                                direction: Axis.vertical,
                                crossAxisAlignment:
                                    WrapCrossAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                 
                                  
                                  
                                  //Email EIT
                                  WidgetInputText(
                                    widgetShade:
                                        Theme.of(context).brightness !=
                                                Brightness.dark
                                            ? Colors.purple
                                            : Colors.pink,
                                    inputHint: "Your Email",
                                    inputIcon: Icons.person,
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                        top: 16, bottom: 16),
                                    width:
                                        MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
                                            .8,
                                    child: Row(
                                      children: [
                                        RoundedButton(
                                          btnText: "Raise Request",
                                          btnColorShade: Theme.of(context)
                                                      .brightness !=
                                                  Brightness.dark
                                              ? Colors.purple
                                              : Colors.pink,
                                        ),
                                        const SizedBox(
                                          width: 16,
                                        ),
                                        RoundedButton(
                                          clickAction: () {
                                            print("CALLED");
                                            Navigator.pop(context);
                                          },
                                          btnText: "Cancel",
                                          btnColorShade: Theme.of(context)
                                                      .brightness !=
                                                  Brightness.dark
                                              ? Colors.pink
                                              : Colors.purple,
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            );
                          })
```

**Code for WidgetInputText**

```html
class WidgetInputText extends StatelessWidget {
  MaterialColor widgetShade;
  String inputHint;

  IconData inputIcon;

  WidgetInputText(
      {super.key,
      required this.widgetShade,
      required this.inputHint,
      required this.inputIcon});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 5),
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .8,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: widgetShade.shade50, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
      child: TextField(
          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelStyle: TextStyle(color: widgetShade),
              labelText: inputHint,
              border: InputBorder.none,
              icon: Icon(
                inputIcon,
                color: widgetShade.shade500,
              ))),
    );
  }
}
```

Below are the problem screen shots

[image: Original Layout]

[image: After Opening the Keyboard]

I have already tried Wrapping BottomSheet into SingleChildScrollView but that didn't work.

I have also tried following with App/Screen Level Scaffold
**resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,**

Above things didn't work for me

Comment: Maybe adding a Padding of `MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets` to your Modalsheet can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside showModalBottomSheet(), wrap your Sizedbox with Padding

```
showModalBottomSheet(
                  context: context,
                  isScrollControlled: true,
                  builder: (BuildContext buildContext) {
                    return Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                          bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
                      child: SizedBox(
                        child: Wrap(
                          direction: Axis.vertical,
                          crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            //...anything else remains same
                            //Email EIT
                            //...
                            ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  });
```

Comment: This worked like charm , Thanks !