Keyboard overlap issue with showModalBottomSheet
I'm unable to show the ModalBottomSheet on top of they keyboard input. Currently the keyboard opens and hides the fields in the back. I have used padding with MediaQuery as seen in other questions but that does not work for me.
Here is the snippet for the ModalBottomSheet:
void _showLoginModal(BuildContext context) {
showModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  isScrollControlled: true,
  isDismissible: false,
  enableDrag: false,
  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async => false,
      child: FractionallySizedBox(
        heightFactor: 0.4,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
              topRight: Radius.circular(20),
            ),
          ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
          child: LoginPage(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
);
}

Now here is the code for the login_page.dart fields:
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: firstNameController,
                    decoration: _buildInputDecoration('First Name'),
                    textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 20),
                Expanded(
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: lastNameController,
                    decoration: _buildInputDecoration('Last Name'),
                    textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10),
            TextField(
              controller: phoneNumberController,
              decoration: _buildInputDecoration('10 digit Mobile Number'),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
              maxLength: 10,
              enabled: !isOtpSent,
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10),
            if (isOtpSent)
              TextField(
                controller: otpController,
                decoration: _buildInputDecoration('Enter OTP'),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              ),
            SizedBox(height: 10),
            ElevatedButton.icon(
              onPressed: () {
                if (isOtpSent) {
                  verifyOtp();
                } else {
                  sendOtp();
                }
              },
              style: ButtonStyle(
                backgroundColor:
                    MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Color(0xFF0194FE)),
                shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                  RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              icon: Icon(Icons.send, color: Colors.white),
              label: Text(
                isOtpSent ? 'Verify OTP' : 'Send OTP',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

Edit
Code changes as per Andrei's post below for feedback and changes, the keyboard issue still persists
  void _setupInitialUserState() {
    // This sets up a timer to check user status and display the login modal if no user is found
    _loginTimer = Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser == null) {
        showSoftKeyboardAwareBottomModal(context);
      }
    });
  }

  Future<void> showSoftKeyboardAwareBottomModal(BuildContext context) async {
    const heightFactor = 0.7;

    await showModalBottomSheet<void>(
      context: context,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      builder: (context) {
        final viewInsets = MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets;
        final screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
        final double modalHeight = screenSize.height * 0.4 - viewInsets.bottom;
        return WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () async => false,
          child: FractionallySizedBox(
            heightFactor: 0.4,
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(20),
                ),
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                    16,
                    16,
                    16,
                    viewInsets
                        .bottom), 
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: modalHeight, // Use calculated height
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: LoginPage(), // Your login page content
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }


https://stackoverflow.com/a/77213250/14071053

@Aks I edited the code as per the comment, yet no change.
return WillPopScope(
onWillPop: () async => false,
child: FractionallySizedBox(
child: Container(
),
child: Padding(
padding: EdgeInsets.only(
bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
),
child: SizedBox(
width: double.infinity,
child: LoginPage(),

In your updated code based on my answer I can still see some problems:
You are not using the heightFactor, you are still using a hardcoded value 0.4 with the FractionallySizedBox . 40% is not enough room for the modal content so the system can't move your inputs into view. If you really want the content of the modal to take 40% you probably want it to be all above the keyboard when it's visible. I'd say:

Remove the FractionallySizedBox widget.
calculate modalHeight = screenSize.height * heightFactor.
This should work even with heightFactor = 0.4


Here's a working example of a modal bottom sheet that is aware of the soft keyboard. It is set to take a percentage of the screen's height (70%) but of course it can be adapted to have different sizes relative to viewInsets.bottom which represents the height of the soft keyboard even during animation.
Also, this example assumes that you want to show scrollable content in the bottom modal sheet.

Recipe summary:

call showModalBottomSeet with isScrollControlled: true
builder returns a SafeArea with a Padding where bottom is at least viewInsets.bottom. You can add an extra value here if you need.
The child of the Padding is a SizedBox specifying the desired height of the scroll viewport. You can play with this value if for example you want the bottom sheet to appear as it is lifted when the keyboard opens. Again, in this example the height is computed so that modal's height stays constant whether the soft keyboard is open or closed.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: TextButton(
          onPressed: () => showSoftKeyboardAwareBottomModal(context),
          child: Text('Show'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> showSoftKeyboardAwareBottomModal(BuildContext context) async {
    const heightFactor = 0.7;

    await showModalBottomSheet<void>(
      context: context,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      builder: (context) {
        final viewInsets = MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets;
        final screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
        final height = screenSize.height * heightFactor - viewInsets.bottom;

        return SafeArea(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 16, 16, viewInsets.bottom),
            child: SizedBox(
              height: height,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Text("Field 1"),
                    TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        isDense: true,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 16),
                    Container(
                      height: 100,
                      color: Colors.blue.shade100,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 100,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 100,
                      color: Colors.blue.shade100,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 100,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Text("Field 2"),
                    TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        isDense: true,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 16),
                    Container(
                      height: 100,
                      color: Colors.blue.shade100,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 100,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 100,
                      color: Colors.blue.shade100,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 100,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 100,
                      color: Colors.blue.shade100,
                    ),
                    Text("Field 3"),
                    TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        isDense: true,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 16),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}


Can you please review the code I've posted above in the edit, which stems from the points you have mentioned here. The issue still persists.

I also did face this issue, follow below steps to resolve this issue:
step 1: showModalBottomSheet ->
isScrollControlled: true,
useSafeArea: true,
context: context,
    
step 2: in scaffold ->
resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
    
step 3: and provide margin to container ->
margin: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(
bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
),

